# Force IIS 7.5 G-Zip for first request

Tags: iis-7.5, gzip

We are having problems with static files like css and js being served without being g-zipped. We use CDN so the number of requests that get to our server farm will be a lot less and this is resulting in IIS 7.5 to serve pages uncompressed. 
I have tried to alter the requentHitThreshold to once every 24 hours but still the problem is if the CDN node is the first one to hit a particular server in the farm it will serve that uncompressed file forever.

So is there anyway to fix this issue? ie.., to force IIS to server G-ZIpped file from the first request.

Any help much appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this? I don't know if it will force the first request or not, though. http://coderjournal.com/2008/04/iis-7-compress-javascript-gzip/